# Android - How to set custom ripple background that works on both L and -L device?

Tags: android

I am implementing a Navigation Drawer like that in Google Play Store, and I want to set selected item of the listview in the DrawerLayout. But then I found that in touch mode items cannot be selected, and one item was set to be checked just after I click it. However all of the item remained the same white background.

I want the checked item have grey highlighted background so I tried View.setBackgroundColor(). But then I found that the ripple effect disappeared! It seemed that the ripple effect is defined in the background resource.

I google everywhere but found no solution. Some results suggest using  tags to make custom background, but  requires API 21.

So finally my question is, how to create custom background that shows ripple effect on L device, while show normal highlight background on pre-L device?

Comment: As an aside, "activated" might be a more apt state for your case, not "selected" (which is akin to "focused"), nor "checked" which doesn't imply exclusivity among its sibling items (multiple items can be checked, only one should be activated). Activated also has the advantage of being an API on View, whereas with checked, you must implement the checkable interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the NavigationView, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog.

Makes all selecting and design simple, and compatible. You can find it in the design support package, http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Gradle/MAven dep:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaat?! So I spent several days implementing an existing things LOL. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an alternative drawable resource: one in `res/drawable` and the other in `res/drawable-v21`.

*res/drawable*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/background_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/background_focused" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/background_default" />
</selector>
```

*res/drawable-v21*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:color="@color/background_ripple" />
```

This should be set as a foreground (available on FrameLayout).

---

weak, I misread the question. You can of course have ripple set as a background - and setting the above drawables as the background to any (clickable) view will enable the ripple effect on lollipop+ and regular focus/press states on pre-lollipop.

If I were in your situation, I would set this as the foreground, and keep the current background that you have (which is dependent on checked state), which should achieve the effect you want, but does not answer the exact question you asked.